# Custom Event not being heard

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm working on a mobile AIR project using Flash Builder 4.6. I'm dispatching a custom Event but it is never being heard. I've checked similar questions but cannot find an answer which solves it for me. In my main mxml file I add the listener in the addedToStage event:

[EDIT] adding the listener to the userStatus instance.  Still not working.

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication
  ...
  private var userStatus:UserStatus;
  protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
   {
     userStatus = new UserStatus(); 
     userStatus.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CREDENTIALS_READY, credentialsReadyHandler);
```

The CustomEvent class:

```
    public class CustomEvent extends Event
{
    public static const CREDENTIALS_READY:String = "credentialsReady";
    public function CustomEvent(customEventString:String){

        super(customEventString, true, false);
    }
}
```

The class which dispatches the CustomEvent after a successful service call:

```
public class UserStatus extends EventDispatcher
{
  ...
    //event handler
    private function userStatusLoaded(e:Event):void 
    {
        var json:Object = JSON.parse(paidUserLoader.data.toString());
        if(json.success == "true")
        {
            trace("UserStatus::this is a paid user!");
            dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CREDENTIALS_READY));
        }
```

I can see the trace statement in the console, so I know the code is getting there. But the listener in the s:ViewNavigatorApplication class never fires.

Can anyone see why?

Thanks.

Comment: `this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CREDENTIALS_READY, credentialsReadyHandler);` Try replacing `this` with the name of your instance of the `UserStatus` class

Comment: @CyanAngel - a good thought. Same result, though -- nothing.

Comment: You can't listen on a parent if the dispatcher isn't a child of said parent

Comment: LDMediaServices as it turns out the UserStatus is not even a DisplayObject so comment does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

Any custom class event has to override the clone() method. This method is automatically called internally but if it's not present (overrided) then only direct dispatch can work but events cannot traverse a hierarchy.

EDIT: nvm, there's no reason for your ViewNavigatorApplication to actually catch that event since UserStatus is not a DisplayObject. You are confused about how event are dispatched and are supposed to work. Only the UserStatus itself can catch the event it is dispatching. No other object can. In the case of a display list event propagate but for all non displayobject they need to catch their own dispatch.

EDIT: Answering comment:

There's somewhere a reference of the UserStatus instance, it might be in the ViewNavigatorApplication or not, if it is then:

```
myuserstatus.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CREDENTIALS_READY, credentialsReadyHandler);
```

would work. If it's not there then you need to pass along the information from whether class having the reference to UserStatus to the ViewNavigatorApplication. This can be done by redispatching the event (this is where you need to override clone()).

The instance of someotherclass has a reference to userstatus and does listen for the event. When the event fires the someotherclass instance catches and redispatches it. The ViewNavigatorApplication listen for that event directly or via the someotherclass instance reference and finally catches the event.

EDIT: responding to new edits

Let's fix your custom event class. By default you set bubbling to true but only DisplayObject can bubble so it should be set to capture (false)

```
super(customEventString, false, false);
```

That should fix it I bet.

Comment: So then how do I communicate with ViewNavigatorApplication to tell it that the credentials are ready?

Comment: thanks. So yes, there is that reference and I tried your myuserstatus.addEventListener suggestion but it doesn't work. If UserStatus is not a Display Object, why would it work? But if you think it worthwhile I will try overriding the clone(). Do I need to change the class from extending EventDispatcher to something on the DisplayList -- say, Sprite?

Comment: No need for clone() then and yes it should work the way it is. If it doesn't then there's another problem. Show the current code you are using now.

Comment: I've tried the suggestion of setting bubbling to false, but it still doesn't work. The only thing I can think to do is to duplicate the code in userStatus and put it in the actual view classes. Poor coding practice, but I don't see what alternative Flex gives me.

Comment: I did put together a simple test and it's working fine. What Flex SDK version are you using? I think ViewNavigatorApplication is deprecated.

Comment: I'm using 4.6.0 build 23201. I ended up just moving the code into the main mxml file. I can then dispatch events from the view.mxml classes and have the code run from the main file. So I avoided duplicating code. You're able to dispatch a custom event from a class which extends EventDispatcher, but which is not on the display list, and have it handled in mxml class?

Comment: Let's be precise, I was able to: have an instance of a class extending EventDispatcher dispatch a custom event, then have that instance referenced in a mxml object listen to its own dispatch and catch the event.

Comment: You might want to look into the concept of an Event Bus, which is just an IEventDispatcher (usually just a plain EventDispatcher) that you pass around to various places in the program that need to communicate without having direct references to one another. So then any instance can dispatch on the event bus and any instance that has a reference to it and is listening will hear it.